# Is it possible to calculate these matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given are two real matrices

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & -3\\ 
0 &-1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1\\ 
4 & -2\\ 
0 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

Is it possible to do the operation $3A+4B^{T}$ with these?

I tried:

$$3\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 5 & -3\\ 
0 &-1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}+4 \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & 0\\ 
1 &-2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$$

And now we multiply:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 15 & -9\\ 
0 &-3 & 18
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
12 & 16 & 0\\ 
4 &-8 & 24
\end{pmatrix}$$

Add then we have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
18 & 31 & -9\\ 
4 &-11 & 42
\end{pmatrix}$$

So I say it's possible and I hope it's correct?

Comment: This seems correct.

Comment: Yes, as the trasnposed matrix defined : $[A^T]_{ij}=[A]_{ji}$. For more information you can read the see the animation - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you don't even need to do the computation to answer your question. You just need to compute the dimensions of the matrices:

$B \ $ is $\ (3 \times 2) \implies B^{T} \ $ is $ \ (2 \times 3)$ which is also the dimension of $A$, so you can perform matrix addition, and since a scalar multiple of a matrix leaves the dimension unchanged you can compute your expression.